# Jasmine runner at '/specs' returned a 302 error: Found

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, jasmine, rspec-rails

I'm using **jasmine-rails-0.4.5** and **devise-2.2.3** in a standard **rails-3.2** app. When I run *bundle exec rake spec:javascript*, in order to run the jasmine specs, I'm getting the following message: "*Jasmine runner at '/specs' returned a 302 error: Found*"

Since I'm using devise any request against the server that is not authenticated yet, it's being redirected to the log-in page. So far so good, that is the expected behavior from devise, but jasmine-rails need to access **the /specs url** in order to run the tests, so when it tries to access this it, it's getting this error: "*Jasmine runner at '/specs' returned a 302 error: Found*"

In my routes.rb file I added this line: "*mount JasmineRails::Engine => "/my_specs" if defined?(JasmineRails)*"

Any clue?
Thanks

Comment: You're being redirected probably because authorization is failing due to devise. Somehow you need to authorize access to this route.

Comment: Yeap, I that was the error. Thanks!

Comment: @EmilianoZilocchi can you share what is the solution for this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what it fixed the issue (I did an upgrade for a newer version):

1. update your js libraries
2. get rid of all the entries under the section "src_files" except for "assets/application.js" on the spec/javascripts/support/jasmine.yml file
3. Add this file:

   `+++ b/spec/javascripts/support/jasmine_helper.rb
   @@ -0,0 +1,13 @@
   +#Use this file to set/override Jasmine configuration options
   +#You can remove it if you don't need it.
   +#This file is loaded *after* jasmine.yml is interpreted.
   +#
   +#Example: using a different boot file.
   +#Jasmine.configure do |config|
   +#   @config.boot_dir = '/absolute/path/to/boot_dir'
   +#   @config.boot_files = lambda { ['/absolute/path/to/boot_dir/file.js'] }
   +#end
   +#
   +
   +Rails.application.config.action_controller.asset_host = "//localhost:8888"
   +Rails.application.config.base_url = ENV['BASE_URL'] || "http://localhost:8888"`
4. Get rid of this file: spec/javascripts/support/jasmine_runner.rb

Hope this helps